# Asymptotic properties of $\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A$ be $n \times n$ matrix with 0 as one eigenvalue and all the other eigen eigenvalues are negative. I am interested in knowing asymptotic properties of solutions of $$\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t)$$

Another related question: if $A$ is a non-negative matrix with $\lambda$ being the Perron-frobenious eigen value $\lambda$, then what can be said about the eigen values of $\frac{A}{\lambda} - I$ ? One eigen value is $0$ for sure, I am interested in knowing about the rest.

Comment: You need also algebraic and geometric multiplicities of this eigenvalue. Everything else will follow easily from Jordan's normal form of A.

Comment: I am a little lost. If all the eigenvalues are distinct then A is diagonolizable. In any case, if you assume that 0 has multiplicity 1, and all other eigenvalues have negative real part then the orbits will converge to the line along the eigenvector of 0.

Comment: @Artem: I couldn't understand the last line. It is not clear to me why the limit will lie in the kernel of A. Looks like I am missing something trivial. Please see the edit.

Comment: Take your matrix, transform it into Jordan's normal form, write the explicit solution. You will see what happens.